# Is there a way to access the instance of a StatefulWidget inside of it's state?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of widgets which I want to update if a button on the inside of one of those widgets is pressed.

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    init();
  }
 
  List<Training> finalTrainings = [];

  void addTraining(Training training){
    setState(() {
      finalTrainings.add(training);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Training(addTraining);
  }
}
```

`addTraining` is the callback function I use

```
class Training extends StatefulWidget {
  const Training({Key? key, required this.addTraining}) : super(key: key);

  final Function addTraining;

  @override
  State<Training> createState() => _TrainingState();
}

class _TrainingState extends State<Training> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ElevatedButton(
      child: Text("add training",),
      onPressed: () {
        widget.addTraining(this);
      },
    )
  }
}
```

Here I use "this" trying to reference the Training instance but obviously this doesn't work, since it just returns the "_TrainingState" instance. Is there a way I can access the Training instance from within _TrainingState?

Comment: I am not exactly sure what it is that you are doing/asking, but does this solve the problem? `widget.addTraining(widget);`

Comment: Yes of course how did I not know?  Thank you so much for commenting. You can post an answer so I can accept yours.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to access the instance of a widget from where you use that widget, you should make the state class public by removing its underscore:

```
class Training extends StatefulWidget {
  const Training({Key? key, required this.addTraining}) : super(key: key);

  final Function addTraining;

  @override
  State<Training> createState() => TrainingState();
}

// state class should be public 
class TrainingState extends State<Training> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ElevatedButton(
      child: Text("add training",),
      onPressed: () {
        widget.addTraining(this);
      },
    )
  }
}
```

then use global key:

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {

  final trainingKey = GlobalKey<TrainingState>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    init();
  }
 
  List<Training> finalTrainings = [];

  void addTraining(Training training){
    // widget instance that you want to access
    final trainingWidget = trainingKey.currentWidget;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Training(key: trainingKey);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering but will this still work if I have many instances of Training?

Comment: each instance must have its own global key

Comment: @lucasfelber accessing the widget instance by passing the instance through a callback is not a good idea. at first, i didn't understand your question correctly. you can use GlobalKey to access widget instance either. I edited my answer for accessing widget instance.